Why does EMR Hudi params settings go wrong with MWAA Airflow?
I am trying to run an EMR cluster from Airflow AWS managed (MWAA) with:
return EmrServerlessStartJobOperator(
            task_id=...,
            application_id=...,
            execution_role_arn=...,
            job_driver=...,
            configuration_overrides={
                "applicationConfiguration": [
                    {
                        "classification": "hudi-defaults",
                        "properties": {
                            "hoodie.metrics.on": "true",
                            "hoodie.metrics.reporter.type": "DATADOG",
                            "hoodie.metrics.datadog.api.site": "EU",
                            "hoodie.metrics.datadog.api.key": ...,
                            "hoodie.metrics.datadog.metric.prefix": ...,
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
            deferrable=True,
            waiter_max_attempts=20,
            waiter_delay=30,
)

but I am getting the following error:
botocore.errorfactory.ValidationException: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the StartJobRun operation: Unknown configuration overrides classification: hudi-defaults

I cannot see what is wrong with my current configuration. Any idea? Or in alternative is there any point in Airflow to enable botocore logs with something like:
boto3.set_stream_logger('botocore')

?

We don't set hudi options in cluster properties but passed to dataframe writer while writing.  Try that maybe?

Are you using emr-serverless?

No, regular EMR clusters

Hey @Randomize, did you manage to publish Hudi metrics to DD using EMR serverless?

@OscarDrai that is an option not available for EMR serverless. It works only for EMR running on EC2 instances.

@Randomize got it thanks. Are you setting these very same properties directly in the table then?

@OscarDrai I was using as workaround a painful approach, publishing some info via DD's API from a separate monitoring process that read info down to S3, like file sizes, etc to keep an eye how data growth etc.

@Randomize yep I wanted to avoid that. I publish Spark's metrics directly to DD's API but would love to avoid doing that for Hudi if it's already built in. Shouldn't we at least be able to use the UserDefinedMetricsReporter? That may be more new-release-friendly if they ever restructure the metadata files? Happy to collaborate and test.
https://hudi.apache.org/docs/next/metrics#userdefinedmetricsreporter

@OscarDrai I would like to collaborate with you on this but I am not working on it anymore (company change) so I am not able to reproduce the process currently.

I remember I have issued a "request for enhancement" to AWS. As the business works, if they get different requests, they might consider to add this feature.
